# Write a set of characters to serial port in c#

Tags: c#

I want to write a set of characters to serial port in c#.

The set of characters are 123456

```
  serialPort1.WriteLine("123456");
```

The above code is not working. So give me some other methods.

Thanks.

Edit:

I do not want to send the string "123456" as a whole. I just want the characters "123456" to be sent one by one to the serial port.

Any ideas ??

Comment: -1 "Not working" is not an error, problem description, or question.

Comment: Why would you assume that there would be multiple methods to do a simple task like writing characters to a serial port?

Comment: The word "serial" in SerialPort means that writing a string is the same as writing chars one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
        String stringToSend = "123456";
        serialPort1.Write(stringToSend.ToCharArray(), 0, stringToSend.Length);
```

Check it out: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2sxhat8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)